# Convert Dialog into an activity in Android

Tags: android

Can we convert an dialog into an activity in android ? 
If yes then how to do that ?

Suppose i have 2 application ... 'Application A' and 'Application B' .. 'Application B' is password protected i.e., when we want to open 'Application B' a password prompt will come..Now 'Application A' is open...but after some time out i want to open 'Application B'..Now the problem is the password prompt of 'Application B' is coming but not on the top...It will be there when we out of the 'Application A',,,So i want there is that password prompt of 'Application B' to come to top of 'Application A'..

Comment: But what is the problem to display Dialog over Activity?

Comment: The dialog is a password prompt...its comming but it is not appearing over the ongoing activity...When i close the present activity then only i am able to see the dialog

Comment: @MD I guess the OP wants to say that, for example, if a `Dialog` is shown in `Activity A` with a delay, meanwhile `Activity B` will come into the foreground and the `Dialog` window will be bound to `Activity A` and thus not visible while `Activity B` is on top

Comment: Suppose i have 2 application ... 'Application A' and 'Application B' .. 'Application B' is password protected i.e., when we want to open 'Application B' a password prompt will come..Now 'Application A' is open...but after some time out i want to open 'Application B'..Now the problem is the password prompt of 'Application B' is coming but not on the top...It will be there when we out of the 'Application A',,,So i want there is that password prompt of 'Application B' to come to top of 'Application A'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we convert an dialog into an activity in android

The answer is no, you cannot *convert* a `Dialog` to an `Activity`. What you are probably looking for is a [Dialog-themed Activity](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/06/android-activity-as-dialog-example.html).

Also refer to the [Dialog docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) for more information.

This is the key part of the whole thing (of course not limited to Holo Light):

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
```

Comment: Thnx.... i got what i was looking for..

Answer (score 0):

Please learn the Activity Life cycle .

> Converting Dialogue into Activity doesn't make sense.

[image]